# Dropzone - is it possible to change the text of the 'Remove file' link after upload?

Tags: javascript, html, css, spring-boot, dropzone.js

I am using `Dropzone` with `jQuery` and `Thymeleaf` in my `Spring MVC` application. The `Dropzone` works brilliantly, and I have been able to customise it with help from SO members! But there is a minor cosmetic issue that I am struggling with.

I am setting `autoProcessQueue` to false, so that the queue is not processed until a submit button is clicked. After uploading files, I would like the 'Remove file' link to remain in place but with different text.

This can be seen in the screenshot below. Three files have already been selected and uploaded by clicking 'Submit'. The user has then selected a new file (on the right), which has not yet been submitted. For the files that have already been uploaded, I want to retain the remove file link, but would like to change the text to be 'Clear file', so that is is distinctly different from the text used for unsubmitted files, which I want to remain as 'Remove file'.

[image: Dropzone]

My Dropzone configuration is pasted below: -

```
Dropzone.options.frmTarget = {
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        paramName: 'file',
        clickable: true,
        maxFilesize: 10,
        uploadMultiple: false,
        parallelUploads: 10,
        maxFiles: 20,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        acceptedFiles: '.png,.jpg,.pdf,.doc,.docx,.xls, .xlsx,.xml,.bmp,.msg,.txt',
        dictDefaultMessage: 'Drag files or click here to select',
        init: function () {
            var myDropzone = this;
            myDropzone.removeAllFiles();

            myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function (file) {
              $("#dropzone-info").show().delay(3500).fadeOut();
            });

            // Update selector to match your button
            $("#button").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                myDropzone.processQueue();
            });
            $("#button1").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
            });
    }
}
```

These are my custom `CSS` changes so far: -

```
.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-progress {
  top: 115% !important;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,90%) !important;
}

.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-success .dz-success-mark {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  -moz-animation: slide-in 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  -ms-animation: slide-in 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  -o-animation: slide-in 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  animation: slide-in 3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
}
```

I would be very grateful for any suggestions and ideas as to whether this may be possible in `CSS` or in `JavaScript`, perhaps by overriding the success function? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the properties **dictRemoveFile** to alter texto of the link remove, and **dictDefaultMessage** to alter your message default of the dropzone.

Ex:

```
const dropzone = new Dropzone("#dropzone-default", {              
    dictDefaultMessage: 'Arraste e solte os arquivos aqui para fazer upload',
    dictRemoveFile: 'Remover',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
})
```